# java generics: defining objects

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to learn Java and having trouble understanding generics. I'm attempting to define an object of Integer data type, then use the object to to call a generic method.

Guided by the API and some web resources, I've been trying all sorts of things but I don't know if i'm on the right track in terms of simply defining the object.

SearchSortAlgorithms.java:

```
public class SearchSortAlgorithms<T> implements SearchSortADT<T>
{
public void quickSort(T[] list, int length)
    {
        recQuickSort(list, 0, length - 1);
    }
}
```

TestQuickSort.java

```
public class TestQuickSort
{  
    static void main(String [] args)
    {  

    // define an Integer array of 50000 elements
    Integer[] anArray = new Integer[5000];

    // load the array with random numbers using
    // a for loop and Math.random() method - (int)(Math.random()*50000)
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
        anArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * i);
    }


    // define an object of SearchSortAlgorithm with Integer data type
    // use this object to call the quickSort method with parameters: your array name and size-50000

    Integer aSortedArray = new Integer(5000);
    public void quickSort(anArray, 5000) {
    TestQuickSort<Integer> aSortedArray = new TestQuickSort<Integer>();
    return aSortedArray.quickSort(anArray, 5000);
    }


    // print out the first 50 array elements with a for loop
    // they have to be sorted now
    for (int k = 0; k <= 50; k++) {
      System.out.print(aSortedArray[k] + " ");
    }

  }

}
```

Errors on these lines:

```
    public int TestQuickSort () {
        TestQuickSort<Integer> aSortedArray = new TestQuickSort<Integer>();
        aSortedArray = quickSort(anArray, 5000);
    }
```

-Illegal start of expression: I wonder if my attempt at creating the constructor is right
-; expected

Comment: Where you are getting the error ? I mean , which line ?

Comment: These in two separate files? Since they're both declared public, they should be.

Comment: I would highly suggest a beginner's book on Java or following the [Generics tutorial provided by oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). As is, your code ... really makes no sense. There are numerous errors and it wouldn't even come close to compiling.

Comment: i just updated my code to reflect your questions

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring any other potential errors in your code (or due to its presentation to us here), you are attempting to declare another method in `main`.

```
public int SearchSortAlgorithm () {
    TestQuickSort<Integer> aSortedArray = new TestQuickSort<Integer>();
    aSortedArray = quickSort(anArray, 5000);
}
```

This *needs* to be moved out of `main`.  And also fixed to actually return an `int`.  And `main`'s signature should be `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Although, it should really be returning an `int[]` instead...

```
public static int[] searchSortAlgorithm (final int[] anArray) {
    TestQuickSort<Integer> aSortedArray = new TestQuickSort<Integer>();
    return quickSort(anArray, 5000);
}
```

...and called in your `main` method like this...

```
int[] aSortedArray = searchSortAlgorithm(anArray);
for (int k = 0; k <= 50; k++) { // would be better to use aSortedArray.length
  System.out.print(aSortedArray[k] + " ");
}
```

Comment: i just updated my code a little @Makoto